# Getting information from tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've two tables in my database:

1. **payments**

> Columns:
>
> - transactionID (primary key)
> - Mid (foreign key)
> - Mname
> - Mnic
> - amount
> - month
> - bank
> - branch
> - depositdate
> - bankdate
> - paydate
> - paymenttype

2. **registration**

> Columns:
>
> - Mid (primary key)
> - Mname
> - Mnic
> - Mbd
> - Muname
> - Mpwd
> - Mutype
> - Mbank
> - Maccn
> - Memail
> - Mphone
> - Mrd

I want to fetch `Mid`, `Mname`, `paymenttype`, `Mphone`, `Memail`, `paydate`.

Comment: I think you just want a basic join between these two tables.  In my opinion, you didn't provide enough information to make this answerable, e.g. you never told us what the join columns are, what the sample data is (so we know if we should inner/left join), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
select registration.Mid,Mname,paymenttype,Mphone,Memail,paydate
from registration
inner join
payments
on registration.Mid=payments.Mid;
```